# Blazor Webassembly - Handling viewport / device-width changes

Tags: css, blazor

Recently I created a Custom Navmenu (using TailwindCSS) in my Blazor WebAssembly project. 
Depending on the device-width a sidebar is being showed / hidden (with the use of Tailwind hidden and device-with CSS classes).

On a specific device-width a menu button is being showed, a div which is specific for the mobile sidebar is always hidden (with display: none), in Blazor I have created an `@onclick` function which sets the style of the mobile sidebar to empty (so display: none is being removed) and vice-versa.

This all works perfectly, however there is one problem with this approach. When the menu button is clicked, the mobile side-bar is being showed, if I now increase the device-width the menu button is being hidden automatically and so is the mobile sidebar, if i then decrease the device-width again the menu button is showed again but the 'opened' sidebar div is also being showed (because in the last smaller device-width is was also opened (style of display:none was removed).

The behavior should be, when the device width is increased the mobile-side bar should always retain its style property display:none.

Though, as far is I know there is no event in Blazor which triggers on a `changed device width`? is there any way to get this working?

Below some images and HTML code which shows the 'problem':

**Normal size view:**
[image]

**Mobile view:**

[image]

**Mobile sidebar opened view:**
[image]

So the problem is that when I go from `Mobile sidebar opened view` back to `Normal size view` and then back to `Mobile view`, it will show the `Mobile sidebar opened view` instead (because it still has an empty style property, which is equivalent to `display: block`)

**The HTML / Blazor C# code :**

```
 <div class="md:hidden" style=@mobileSideBarDisplay> <!-- Blazor C# string that sets the display to display: none, or removes the display entirely to show it)
    <div class="fixed inset-0 flex z-40">

    <!--
      Off-canvas menu overlay, show/hide based on off-canvas menu state.

      Entering: "transition-opacity ease-linear duration-300"
        From: "opacity-0"
        To: "opacity-100"
      Leaving: "transition-opacity ease-linear duration-300"
        From: "opacity-100"
        To: "opacity-0"
    -->
        <div class="fixed inset-0">
            <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-600 opacity-75"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- The menu item with is Blazor onclick event -->
        <div class="relative flex-1 flex flex-col max-w-xs w-full pt-5 pb-4 bg-gray-800">
            <div class="absolute top-0 right-0 -mr-14 p-1">
                <button class="flex items-center justify-center h-12 w-12 rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-600" aria-label="Close sidebar" @onclick="ToggleSidebar">
                    <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-white" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>


            <! -- rest of HTML, left out for readability -->
        </div>
     </div>
</div>



<!-- Static sidebar for desktop -->
<div class="hidden md:flex md:flex-shrink-0">
    <div class="flex flex-col w-64">

        <! -- rest of HTML, left out for readability -->


    </div>
</div>


<!-- Horizontal navbar with the Menu button -->
<div class="flex flex-col w-0 flex-1 overflow-hidden">
    <div class="relative z-10 flex-shrink-0 flex h-16 bg-white shadow">

        <!-- menu button becomes visible at a certain device-width > done with the TailWind CSS class md:hidden -->
        <button class="px-4 border-r border-gray-200 text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-600 md:hidden" aria-label="Open sidebar" @onclick="ToggleSidebar">
            <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h7" />
            </svg>
        </button>

    <! -- rest of HTML, left out for readability -->

    </div>
</div>



<!-- C# code for viewing mobile sidebar on Menu button press -->
@code {

    private bool showMobileSideBar = false;

    private string mobileSideBarDisplay => showMobileSideBar ? "" : "display: none;";

    private void ToggleSidebar()
    {
        showMobileSideBar = !showMobileSideBar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need js interop and the window.resize event.

There are libraries that can help, like this one https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/BlazorSize

Comment: Hoped for a more native / non-package / non-JS solution but this will do perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: At this point, there is no blazor wrapper for these events. I kind of doubt that the framework will ever do that for you, though.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for anybody else who is here and interested in using a UI library.

In addition to [@rdmpton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812369/rdmptn)'s answer, [MudBlazor](https://mudblazor.com/) has a [component](https://mudblazor.com/components/breakpointprovider#how-it-works): `<MudBreakpointProvider>` which lets you get access to window resize values.

Check out the [Getting Started Docs](https://mudblazor.com/getting-started/installation#manual-install).

Use it like this:

```html
<MudBreakpointProvider>
    <MudHidden Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Xl" Invert="true">
        <MudCard Class="pa-5">
            <MudText>XL</MudText>
        </MudCard>
    </MudHidden>

    <MudHidden Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Lg" Invert="true">
        <MudCard Class="pa-5">
            <MudText>LG</MudText>
        </MudCard>
    </MudHidden>

    <MudHidden Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Md" Invert="true">
        <MudCard Class="pa-5">
            <MudText>MD</MudText>
        </MudCard>
    </MudHidden>

    <MudHidden Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" Invert="true">
        <MudCard Class="pa-5">
            <MudText>SM</MudText>
        </MudCard>
    </MudHidden>

    <MudHidden Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Xs" Invert="true">
        <MudCard Class="pa-5">
            <MudText>XS</MudText>
        </MudCard>
    </MudHidden>
</MudBreakpointProvider>
```

Moreover, they have tons of other components to help you build nice UIs.